# Apps crashed when sending an image android ShareCompat and FileProvider

Tags: android, sharing

The relevant apps appear on screen to share to but when you select one of them, the selected app crashes. WhatsApp says "file format not supported".

```
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath); // image path from mediastore
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "my.app.fileprovider",
            imageFile);

    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType(getContentResolver().getType(contentUri))
            .setStream(contentUri)
            .getIntent();

    shareIntent.setData(contentUri);
    shareIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Select App"));
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of `setData()`. You provide the stream through `setStream()` on the `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Aye! Thanks a lot. That actually worked